# 'Cannot invoke push(double) on the array type double[]'?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, ide

Just kind of getting started with java and wanted to create a basic program that filters grades into different arrays given certain conditions. I keep getting a "Cannot invoke push(double) on the array type double[]" error on VS and on command prompt it gives me an  error 'cannot find symbol' for .push(grade[i]) for each of my array groups (A,B,C,D,F). The variables are declared, I tried giving the arrays a [size] and it still didn't do anything. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    class gradeCalc { 
        public static void main(String args[]) { 
            double [] grade = {89, 89.2, 44.2, 69.6, 79.2, 54.2};
            int count;
            int i;
            double [] Agroup = {};
            double [] Bgroup = {};
            double [] Cgroup = {};
            double [] Dgroup = {};
            double [] Fgroup = {};
            count = 0;


            for(i = 0; i <= grade.length; i++)   
            {
                if (grade[i] >= 80) 
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    Agroup.push(grade[i]);
                }
                else if (grade[i] >= 70) 
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    Bgroup.push(grade[i]);
                }
                else if (grade[i] >= 60) 
                {
                    count = count+ 1;
                    Cgroup.push(grade[i]);
                }
                else if (50 <= grade[i] && grade[i] < 60) 
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    Dgroup.push(grade[i]);
                }
                else 
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    Fgroup.push(grade[i]);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("The total count is: " + count);
            System.out.println("A group : " + Agroup);
            System.out.println("B group : " + Bgroup);
            System.out.println("C group : " + Cgroup);
            System.out.println("D group : " + Dgroup);
            System.out.println("F group : " + Fgroup);
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript is not java.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to mix java with javascript. Push is not function for array in java . You can obtain the same result using the following code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class gradeCalc {

    // Function to add x in arr
    public static double[] addX(int n, double arr[], double x) {
        int i;

        // create a new array of size n+1
        double newarr[] = new double[n + 1];

        // insert the elements from
        // the old array into the new array
        // insert all elements till n
        // then insert x at n+1
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i];

        newarr[n] = x;

        return newarr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double[] grade = { 89, 89.2, 44.2, 69.6, 79.2, 54.2 };
        int count;
        int i;
        double[] Agroup = {};
        double[] Bgroup = {};
        double[] Cgroup = {};
        double[] Dgroup = {};
        double[] Fgroup = {};
        count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
            if (grade[i] >= 80) {
                count = count + 1;

                // Agroup.push(grade[i]);
                Agroup = addX(Agroup.length, Agroup, grade[i]);
            } else if (grade[i] >= 70) {
                count = count + 1;
                Bgroup = addX(Bgroup.length, Agroup, grade[i]);
            } else if (grade[i] >= 60) {
                count = count + 1;

                Cgroup = addX(Cgroup.length, Cgroup, grade[i]);
            } else if (50 <= grade[i] && grade[i] < 60) {
                count = count + 1;

                Dgroup = addX(Dgroup.length, Dgroup, grade[i]);
            } else {
                count = count + 1;
                Fgroup = addX(Fgroup.length, Fgroup, grade[i]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The total count is: " + count);
        System.out.println("A group : " + Arrays.toString(Agroup));
        System.out.println("B group : " + Arrays.toString(Bgroup));
        System.out.println("C group : " + Arrays.toString(Cgroup));
        System.out.println("D group : " + Arrays.toString(Dgroup));
        System.out.println("F group : " + Arrays.toString(Fgroup));
    }
}
```